# How to check dataset datarow exist or not

Tags: c#-4.0

```
Dataset dataset=dalVehicalInfo.GetVehiInfo(servparameters);
DataRow dtrow= dataset.Tables[0].Rows[2]
```

this give position error. So how to check  datarow exist or not in c#?

Answer (score 0):

You can check

```
  dataset.Tables[0].Rows.Count
```

If it is >=3, then `Rows[2]` exists.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like:

```
If (yourRowToCheck < dataset.Tables[0].Rows.Count)
{
    //Exists
    //Do something
}
else
{
    //Not exists
    //Do something else
}
```